# How to extract planar image from CoreImage?

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, rendering, core-image

In my app, I do a lot of image transformations in a context where they need to be as fast as possible. There are 3 steps:

1- feed data into a CIImage
2- transform that image using filters
3- extract the processed pixel data in the expected format.

My issue is step 3. I could only render the output CIImage into 8-bit RGBA, using this call:

```
CIImage *outputImage = gExitFilter.outputImage;
CGImageRef finalImage = [gCoreImageContext createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:outputImage.extent];
CFDataRef imageData = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(finalImage));
```

It so happens that in some cases, I need the output in planar gray format (both 8-bit integer and 32-bit float are required).

Of course, in most cases I can further transform the data from the code above back into the expected format (e.g. using vImage). But that is wasteful to me. Isn't there a way to directly render the CIImage into some specified pixel format?

And there are cases where such a convert step is not actually possible in a lossless way: when the desired output format is planar 32-bit float, converting from 8-bit RGBA will be quite coarse.

I would expect there to be a solution, since step 1 allows for that, using code such as the following:

```
CIImage *inputImage = [CIImage imageWithBitmapData:self.backingData bytesPerRow:bytesPerRow size:fullSize format:kCIFormatR8 colorSpace:gDeviceGrayColorSpace];
```

`kCIFormatR8` here lets me input a planar 8 bit image into the red channel of the CIImage, from whence it's easy with a filter to copy it into the other channels.

With all this context, my question boils down to:

Is there a way to render a CIImage into a one-channel planar image?

(my app is a MacOS X app, but an answer for iOS might be interesting too, and perhaps point me in the right direction)

Edit: I found this method:

```
- (CGImageRef)createCGImage:(CIImage *)im fromRect:(CGRect)r format:(CIFormat)f colorSpace:(CGColorSpaceRef)cs
```

Which looks like it's exactly what I needed. However I wasn't able to use it effectively. Any suggestion welcome.

Answer (score 0):

To render just one channel of a CIImage you should:

- Use the CIColorMatrix filter splat the desired channel in to R,G and B.
- Use [CIContext render:toBitmap:format:kCIFormatR8]